# MVC Core: Wrong link url without trailing slash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i have developed a mvc core 2.1 web-app which is deployed under iis.
But i have a problem with the routing engine.
everything works fine, when i call the website with this url:

https://hostname/subfolder1/subfolder2**/**

but when i call the website without the trailing slash (https://hostname/subfolder1/subfolder2), my links on the main page didnt work, because they pointed to a wrong url.
the right url is: https://hostname/subfolder1/subfolder2/link1?param=HelloWorld

if i call the main page without the trailing slash, the links looks like this:
https://hostname/subfolder1/link1?param=HelloWorld

so one subfolder is missing.

my route is:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Portal}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
```

this is the relevant code of my view:

```
<a class="app-tile" href="@app.Url" title="@app.Description" >
```

where @app.Url looks like "./link1?param=HelloWorld"

so what i have to do to make it possible to use both urls (with and without trailing slash)?

maybe redirect all request without slash to the url with slash? but what is the best practise to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at Areas? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1 
this might help

Comment: this doesnt work in my case. i forgot to say, that subfolder1 and subfolder2 are virtual directories in IIS. they are not direct included in my project

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using relative URLs and based on the presence or not of the slash at the end of the base URL, they will be handled differently.

1. With a slash at the end, the base URL is interpreted as a directory, so having a link to something like `link1` will be interpreted as being *underneath* that directory.
2. Without the slash at the end, the base URL is interpreted as a *file*, so a link to something like `link1`, will be interpreted as a sibling in the same directory, i.e. the part of the path that *does* have a trailing slash.

This has nothing to do with your app, specifically, it's how relative URLs are handled by all browsers. The fix is to use relative absolute URLs for links, images, scripts, etc. Basically it means you reference everything from the document root level, with a preceding slash. So, instead of something like:

```
<a href="link1">Link 1</a>
```

Use instead:

```
<a href="/subfolder1/subfolder2/link1">
```

In that way, you remove the ambiguity around how the base URL and link URL paths should be joined, and it's *always* a good URL regardless of the presence of the trailing slash.

As far as ASP.NET Core goes, if you use the built in URL generation functionality, it will handle affixing things like virtual paths such to the start of the your links for you. For example, if your site is hosted in a virtual directory under under your domain at `/subfolder1`, then when you do something like:

```
<a asp-action="Link1Action" asp-controller="Subfolder2">Link 1</a>
```

Then the href attribute that is generated will be the proper `/subfolder1/subfolder2/link1`.

You can also use `Url.Content`, which will map to the document root of your site:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/subfolder2/link1")">Link 1</a>
```

Then, assuming your root is `http://hostname/subfolder1`, it will again create the correct URL you need. In Razor views, you can also shorthand this to just:

```
<a href="~/subfolder2/link1`>Link 1</a>
```

The `~/` construction is not supported in URLs, but Razor understands that as a reference to your document root, and will parse and substitute the correct URL as it's rendering your view for the response.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure routeOptions to AppendTrailingSlash or remove it. see below example

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.AppendTrailingSlash = true);
```

Comment: This cannot remove a trailing slash

Comment: Not sure if I'm using this correctly but on my test system if I use `pattern: "/MYAPP/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"` and `services.Configure<RouteOptions>` as you have above, does not work.